# Absolute value of all the elements of Hermitian matrix - when can the lowest eigenvalue shrink?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider some $N \times N$ Hermitian matrix $H = (h_{ij})$ and order its eigenvalues from least to greatest, $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_N$.

When does the matrix $H' = (|h_{ij}|)$ have a smaller smallest eigenvalue; that is, when is $\lambda'_1 < \lambda_1$?

To be more concrete, why does it appear that $\lambda'_1 < \lambda_1$ is never true for $2 \times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ matrices, but it can be true for $4 \times 4$ matrices (see below)?

---

This matrix $H'$ takes the modulus of every element of the Hermitian $H$, and so it's real symmetric. Thus its eigenvalues are still real, so the problem is well-posed. All of its entries are non-negative, so I'm wondering if some version of Perron-Frobenius could be used in this case.

Playing around with $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ matrices like $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1-i \\ 1+i & 3 \end{pmatrix},$$ I keep getting $\lambda'_1 \geq \lambda_1$.

However, numerically picking a $4 \times 4$ or $5 \times 5$ matrix at random, I can (with very low probability) get $\lambda'_1 < \lambda_1$. For example,

$$\begin{pmatrix} 4 & -3 & 1 & 2 \\ -3 & 8 & 4 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 & 2 & 5 \\2 & 1 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix},$$

has numerically a lowest eigenvalue of $-2.76...$, but the absolute value matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 8 & 4 & 1 \\ 1 & 4 & 2 & 5 \\2 & 1 & 5 & 4 \end{pmatrix},$$

has numerically a lowest eigenvalue of $-2.91...$. Thus it seems something changes when the matrices get large enough!