# Is the minimum eigenvalue of "$-|H|$" ever larger than that of $H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider a Hermitian matrix $H = (h_{ij})$ and its smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_1$.

Construct the matrix $H' = (-|h_{ij}|)$ and consider its smallest eigenvalue $\lambda'_1$. All of its eigenvalues are real by virtue of $H'$ being real and symmetric.

Is it possible for $\lambda'_1 > \lambda_1$?

---

This problem is a sort of converse [to one I recently asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453754/absolute-value-of-all-the-elements-of-hermitian-matrix-when-can-the-lowest-eig), which noted that the matrix $H'' = (|h_{ij}|)$ can have its lowest eigenvalue either smaller or larger than $\lambda_1$, at least when $N>3$ (for $N=1,2,3$ it appears the lowest eigenvalue of $H''$ is never smaller than that of $H$).

However, for the question currently asked, I don't see any such counterexamples with $\lambda_1' > \lambda_1$ when numerically checking random matrices, which motivates my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the min-max theorem to prove this. Let $|\phi\rangle$ denote the eigen-vector corresponding to the min eigenvalue of $H$. Then the eigenvalue is given by
$$
\langle \phi|H\phi\rangle=\sum_{i,j} \phi(i)^* h_{ij} \phi(j)
$$
Where $|i\rangle$ is your standard orthonormal basis and $\phi(i) =\langle i|\phi\rangle$. Now we always have
\begin{align}
\langle \phi|H\phi\rangle&\ge -\sum_{i,j} |\phi(i)||\phi(j)||h_{ij}| \\
&=-\langle |\phi|||H||\phi|\rangle
\end{align}
Where $-|H|$ is entry-wise calculation and similarly for $|\phi|$. By the min-max theorem, the RHS is $\ge$ the min eigenvalue of $-|H|$ and thus the statement follows.